# Inserting data into a SQL table but getting a specific column data from another table with different column names

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I am looking for some help,

I have two tables, one being **users** and another being **land**. users can have many pieces of land.

my users table holds - ID | USERNAME | PASS
The Land table holds - ID | Land_ID |Land_Name

I am trying to create an SQL statement that will allow me to create a new 'land' record but it will populate the 'Land_ID' with the 'ID' from the users table. Therefore:

The user with ID 1 has land name green which has the Land_ID 1 meaning they own that land?

I hope that makes sense.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: So you're trying to create an `INSERT` statement.  Have you started with some tutorials on MySQL?  (And PHP, since you tagged that as well?)  Where are you stuck?  Inserting a record into a table, and including dynamic values in that record, is covered by just about any tutorial.

Comment: Hello David, I have the SQL
$sql = "INSERT INTO land (land_id, land_name) VALUES ('land_ID????', '$land_Name')"; but I want the land_ID field to populated with the unique id from the users table

Comment: Ok, and how will you know which ID value to use?  What is the logic to determine that?

Comment: the user is logged in and I am collecting the ID to hold the session

Comment: So use the ID that's in the session value?  Your example already shows you using a PHP variable in your query, so what's stopping you from using another PHP variable in your query?  (Note: This is wide open to SQL injection.  You might want to take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$var = $session_id; //use whatever variable you use when collecting the session id, from what I gather you are using the unique id from the users table for this.

$sql = "INSERT INTO land (land_id, land_name) VALUES ('$var', '$land_name')"
```

Extra info:

If this is coming from an HTML form you can input the users session id as a hidden input:

```
<input type = "hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo['id']; ?>">
```

In this case you could then define the variable as:

```
$var = $_POST['id'];
```